# Deploy Spring MVC in WSO2 Application Server

Tags: spring-mvc, wso2

I am trying to deploy my Spring MVC application on WSO2 Application Server by going to Main > Manage > Applications > Add > Web Applications and upload my Spring MVC's WAR file. The upload completed successfully, but I still can't run the web app itself. The error message just basically complaining it doesn't have org.springframework.

The same WAR file can be run on Apache Tomcat with no problem at all. All I did is dropping the same WAR file to \webapps, and it works.

Is there a special setting that needs to be configured to get Spring MVC run on WSO2 Application Server? I would assume WSO2 Application is also using Apache Tomcat, so why it won't run by just uploading the WAR file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by:

1. Upgrading WSO2 AS to latest version (5.1.0) as mentioned by Sagara Gunathunga. For some reasons, previous WSO2 AS doesn't take my JSTL templating (something like $ {blabla}). Only in 5.1.0 did the issue resolved. I start to wonder what this WSO2 is doing with its half-baked product.
2. Modify Maven POM file, specifically slf4j-api dependency. WSO2 has its own slf4j-api library and I have to set the scope of slf4j-api in my app to "provided" before deploying to WSO2. This solve the issue with unable to load all JavaScript files.
   Downside for this is you will need the scope of slf4j-api to be "compiled" when you run this locally under regular Tomcat. Setting it to "provided" will not work under Tomcat. But in WSO2, the scope will need to be "provided" to run. So, there is manual work to change before deploying the application.
   I did try to match the slf4j-api version to match what WSO2 and set the scope to "compile", but it still won't work. WSO2, for some bad reasons, can't use my app's compiled slf4j-api.

Answer (score 1):

What is your WSO2 AS version ? please make sure to use latest AS 5.1.0 version. We have tested large number of Spring (including SpringMVC) based applications on AS 5.1.0, basically if something working on Tomcat it should be work on WSO2 AS too.  If you still have issues on AS 5.1.0 please let me know.

Comment: This fixed half of my problem, which is templating issue with ${ }, it wasn't working on previous version, but now it does.

Comment: Sagara, you statement "... if something working on Tomcat, it should be work on WSO2 AS too." is not 100% true. See my answer on issue with slf4j-api dependency. It's working with "compiled" scope under Tomcat, but not under WSO2 AS.

Answer (score 0):

yes there is a separate workaround to deploy a spring service to wso2 appserver. Please follow [1] for instructions.

[1]. http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/AS510/Spring+Services

Thank you,
Dharshana

Comment: Thanks Dharshana, but I am looking for a Spring MVC web app, not a Spring service.

Answer (score 0):

@stack247,
Well I'm from WSO2 and it's nice to hear that your JSTL issue is solved by now. But I completely disagree with " I start to wonder what this WSO2 is doing with its half-baked product" statement. You may know that spec like Servelt , JSP and JSTL having different versions and update it's version with time. Previous version of application server does not supported for latest JSP 2.0 and JSTL 1.2 specs hence you can't use application which depends on JSP 2.0 or JSTL 1.2 that was a known limitation but can't consider it as half-baked product due to that. This is very common nature with any software product and that's why we are actively developing, fixing issues, upgrading dependencies and frequently  releasing new versions, also we are responding to community issues like this.

With Latest AS 5.1.0 release we officially support for Servelt 3.0, JSP 2.0 and JSTL 1.2 and any dependent applications too. When it come to logging case most of the application server having their own logging mechanisms and some cases it's required remove logging dependencies from applications.

Comment: I am sorry if I offended you with my comment. I have just been working with WSO2 for a past month or so, that includes WSO2 IS and others. I haven't had a true success in learning / implementing the product just yet. Whilst with product like Spring MVC, in about the same time I spent with WSO2, I have achieved a lot. I give you an example. WSO2 IS just recently supporting AD 'properly'. And by properly I mean wire up with the User and Group altogher. When I was toying around with WSO2 IS (ver 4.1), the User and Group weren't properly linked to each other.

Comment: That's not to mention I have to spend a full good week to figure out hooking it up with AD. Documentation and community support have been really low. With such product, I question WSO2 in term of claiming big-names using their products. After all, how can such big names using product that doesn't do its job properly. Now, if the website says those big names using specific product (like WSO2 ESB), that makes more sense. Don't get me wrong, WSO2 ESB is probably awesome in its own way. And again, sorry if I offended you.

Comment: WSO2 has a huge learning curve. We are just beginning a full WSO2 project (IS, ESB, DA integration, APIM, etc.) and are suffering it. Sagara, please correct your grammar corrector, as it is always writing Servelt instead of Servlet.